# Is it safe to create a new app with updated tech using old package name in react native?

Tags: react-native

I just upgraded my react-native project to the latest 0.67 version from 0.62 and also gradle from  4.1.0 to 7.1.0 but my app is crashing not even opening after build for release

So I am thinking to create a fresh app with the same package name and then upload again to google play store will google accept it as an update or it will be problematic ?

Please help me i already wasted my 3 days in trying solving crash error .

Comment: I just updated from 0.63.2 to 0.66.3 (a certain dependency didn't have support for 0.67 yet) yesterday and it was painful. Checkout the update helper https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ I ended up creating a new project using `npx react-native init AwesomeProject --version X.XX.X` and compared the 2 for differences and got things working again

Comment: Theoretically if you have the same package name, `com.etc` and use the same signing certificate you should be able to upload a "new" app. Pretty low risk to test it too, if google play accepts the app when uploading you should be good

Comment: Thanks @b.stevens.photo i am also doing the same i have also created new app and now comparing both lets me check if i can find any solution or else i will create new project with same package name